# How can i export line records to excel in navision using c/al code

Tags: navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav, cal

I am looking for a way to export line records to excel in navision using c/al code by clicking on export button.

And also import that same record back.

I dont know how to go about it. Your help is apprecatiated.

Comment: Could you *at least* specify the version of Nav you are using...

Comment: @MakSim I am using Nav 2017. Though I have been able to achieve it using Excel Buffer